# Why does my Vuejs/Express app work locally but is blank/no products when deployed?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, vuejs2, vercel

I built a Vuejs front-end and express/node/mongodb backend - it works when I use my localhost but after running the build on the frontend, pasting the 'dist' folder in the backend and then deploying to Vercel/Render - I get a blank page with a 404 error for my backend and my deployed frontend just has a header with no products (it's an ecommerce site).

I understand the 404 is a connection error but I'm checking my server.js and I'm not seeing any syntax errors.  One aspect I'm not clear on is the environment variables, I have them inserted into the routes and also created a .env file with the values but not sure if I was supposed to do that second step? Note: I did add the environment variables/values in the settings of the deployment. I've never deployed an app with a separate backend/frontend so I'm fuzzy on the details of how it's all supposed to work in being deployed (as in, do I only need to deploy the backend since it has the dist folder? Is it considered a static site?).

Here is my server.js:

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";
import path from "path";
import history from "connect-history-api-fallback";


const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../assets")));
app.use(
  express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist"), {
    maxAge: "1y",
    etag: false,
  })
);
app.use(history());

app.get("/api/products", async (req, res) => {
  const client = await MongoClient.connect(
    process.env.MONGO_USER && process.env.MONGO_PASS
      ? `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_PASS}@cluster0.ko5dl9a.mongodb.net/${process.env.MONGO_DBNAME}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
      : "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
  );
  const db = client.db(process.env.MONGO_DBNAME || "vue-db");
  const products = await db.collection("products").find({}).toArray();
  res.status(200).json(products);
  client.close();
});

app.get("/api/users/:userId/cart", async (req, res) => {
  const { userId } = req.params;
  const client = await MongoClient.connect(
    process.env.MONGO_USER && process.env.MONGO_PASS
      ? `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_PASS}@cluster0.ko5dl9a.mongodb.net/${process.env.MONGO_DBNAME}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
      : "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }
  );
  const db = client.db(process.env.MONGO_DBNAME || "vue-db");
  const user = await db.collection("users").findOne({ id: userId });
  if (!user) return res.status(404).json("Could not find user");
  const products = await db.collection("products").find({}).toArray();
  const cartItemsIds = user.cartItems;
  const cartItems = cartItemsIds.map((id) =>
    products.find((product) => product.id === id)
  );
  res.status(200).json(cartItems);
  client.close();
});

app.get("/api/products/:productId", async (req, res) => {
  const { productId } = req.params;
  const client = await MongoClient.connect(
    process.env.MONGO_USER && process.env.MONGO_PASS
      ? `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_PASS}@cluster0.ko5dl9a.mongodb.net/${process.env.MONGO_DBNAME}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
      : "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }
  );
  const db = client.db(process.env.MONGO_DBNAME || "vue-db");
  const product = await db.collection("products").findOne({ id: productId });
  if (product) {
    res.status(200).json(product);
  } else {
    res.status(404).json("Could not find product");
  }
  client.close();
});

app.post("/api/users/:userId/cart", async (req, res) => {
  const { userId } = req.params;
  const { productId } = req.body;
  const client = await MongoClient.connect(
    process.env.MONGO_USER && process.env.MONGO_PASS
      ? `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_PASS}@cluster0.ko5dl9a.mongodb.net/${process.env.MONGO_DBNAME}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
      : "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }
  );
  const db = client.db(process.env.MONGO_DBNAME || "vue-db");
  await db.collection("users").updateOne(
    { id: userId },
    {
      $addToSet: { cartItems: productId },
    }
  );

  const user = await db.collection("users").findOne({ id: userId });
  const products = await db.collection("products").find({}).toArray();
  const cartItemsIds = user.cartItems;
  const cartItems = cartItemsIds.map((id) =>
    products.find((product) => product.id === id)
  );

  res.status(200).json(cartItems);
  client.close();
});

app.delete("/api/users/:userId/cart/:productId", async (req, res) => {
  const { userId, productId } = req.params;
  const client = await MongoClient.connect(
    process.env.MONGO_USER && process.env.MONGO_PASS
      ? `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_PASS}@cluster0.ko5dl9a.mongodb.net/${process.env.MONGO_DBNAME}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
      : "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }
  );
  const db = client.db(process.env.MONGO_DBNAME || "vue-db");

  await db.collection("users").updateOne(
    { id: userId },
    {
      $pull: { cartItems: productId },
    }
  );
  const user = await db.collection("users").findOne({ id: userId });
  const products = await db.collection("products").find({}).toArray();
  const cartItemsIds = user.cartItems;
  const cartItems = cartItemsIds.map((id) =>
    products.find((product) => product.id === id)
  );
  res.status(200).json(cartItems);
  client.close();
});

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../dist/index.html"));
});
//  app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
//     res.send('Hello!')
//  })

//  app.post('/hello', (req, res) => {
//     res.send(`Hello ${req.body.name}`)
//  })

//  app.get('/hello/:name', (req, res) => {
//     res.send(`Hello ${req.params.name}`)
//  })

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000, () => {
  console.log("Server is listening on port 8000");
});
```

and here is my package.json if it helps:

```
{
  "name": "fsv-back-end",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel ./src --out-dir ./build",
    "start": "node ./build/server.js",
    "dev": "npx nodemon --exec npx babel-node src/server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.22.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^2.0.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongodb": "^5.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.21.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.1",
    "@babel/node": "^7.22.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.22.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22"
  }
}
```